# How to download file to specific location using WebClient's download

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
namespace Garfield
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            download("https://d1ejxu6vysztl5.cloudfront.net/comics/garfield/2019/2019-11-25.gif?v=1.1", "e.gif");

        }
        public void download(string link, string name)
        {
            using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
            {
                Client.DownloadFile(link, name);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Using the code above I downloaded an image online, now how do I set the location of that file to somewhere else instead of it being in the `debug` folder?

Comment: Specify a path in front of the filename.

Comment: you mean as a separate argument before "e.gif"?

Comment: See answer. You just add the path to the filename's string.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through mentioning a valid desired location and name when download.

```
Client.DownloadFile("https://d1ejxu6vysztl5.cloudfront.net/comics/garfield/2019/2019-11-25.gif?v=1.1",
    @"C:\yourfolder\yourfilename.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an entire path to your `download` method:

```
download("https://d1ejxu6vysztl5.cloudfront.net/comics/garfield/2019/2019-11-25.gif?v=1.1", "C:\\Users\\(You)\\Documents\\e.gif");
```

Just replace everything before `"e.gif"` with the path you desire.

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.8